# Is there a way to count not blank cell in a row with a specific column criteria from a header

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can I count the number of not blank cell (negative and positive) in each row where the column consist "s*" in the header? The file I have made is huge and this is counted manualy;

[image: This is small example of my file]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
O2: =COUNTIFS($A$1:$N$1,"s*",A2:N2,"<>")
```

and fill down

[image]

Comment: Brilliant - it works & I can't describe my thanks to you!

Answer (score 1):

At first glance I am not sure how to get a count by conventional means, but you could always test each respective row individually, convert the Boolean to it's numeric counterpart, and then only count instances where both conditions are met.

For instance:

```
=SUM(IF(
--(IFERROR(SEARCH("r", $A$14:$E$14)>0, FALSE))+
IF(ISBLANK(A18:E18), 0, 1)=2, 1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Or if the range contains formulas use: `=SUM(ISNUMBER(FIND("r",$A$14:$E$14))*(LEN(A18:E18)>0))`

Comment: =COUNT(FIND("s",A$1:N$1)/A2:N2)  This is for your reference only.

Comment: @Can.U nice! Just have to make sure the character you're looking for appears first and that is the cleanest of the 3 answers I think

Comment: @Can.U very clean. Only sidenote is that if Value `0` would be used it's not counted.

Comment: =SUM(IF(
--(IFERROR(SEARCH("r", $A$14:$E$14)>0, FALSE))+
IF(ISBLANK(A18:E18), 0, 1)=2, 1,0)) 

 + (ctrl + shift + enter) - Yes, you're great! 
I have now 3 solutions - respect @Euler'sDisgracedStepchild; @Can.U; @P.b